# Query for the allowed values in a constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, constraints, ddl

I want to extract values from a `CHECK` constraint on a database table. The code is:

```
CONSTRAINT Shop_check_serviceType CHECK (service_type IN ('food or drink', 'entertainment', 'retail'))
```

In Postgres 12 there is a column named `consrc` in  `pg_catalog.pg_constraint`. But I use Postgres 14 and I don't know how to extract the values there. I have tried to search the manual without success.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dedicated function [`pg_get_constraintdef()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to reverse-engineer the SQL-DDL code of constraint definition.

```sql
SELECT pg_get_constraintdef(oid)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_constraint
WHERE  contype  = 'c'                          -- CHECK constraint
AND    conrelid = 'public.my_table'::regclass  -- your table name here
AND    connname = 'shop_check_servicetype';    -- lower-cased?
```

If you did not double-quote the constraint name "Shop_check_serviceType" it has been converted to lower-case.

Related:

- [Delete rows with foreign key in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182079/delete-rows-with-foreign-key-in-postgresql/14182346#14182346)

BTW, the (redundant) column [`consrc` existed up to Postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/catalog-pg-constraint.html) and had already been dropped from `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` in Postgres 12. `pg_get_constraintdef()` reproduces what used to be in that column.

Quoting the [release notes of Postgres 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.14.4):

> - Remove obsolete [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/catalog-pg-constraint.html).`consrc` column (Peter Eisentraut)
>
>   This column has been deprecated for a long time, because it did not
>   update in response to other catalog changes (such as column
>   renamings). The recommended way to get a text version of a check
>   constraint's expression from pg_constraint is `pg_get_expr(conbin, conrelid)`. `pg_get_constraintdef()` is also a useful alternative.

Comment: Thank u very much! Its working

Comment: @Στέφανος If that answers your question properly, consider accepting it.