# Loop with many DELETEs not finishing even though the statements complete OK

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-delete, dynamic-sql

I have a function that deletes rows from many tables, as much as 130+ tables, in a loop. The problem isn't the `DELETE` statements themselves, they seem to complete fine in a timely fashion, but for some reason, the `LOOP` take much more time to exit.

Here's the function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.delete_dependents(p_id smallint)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    v_query_delete          TEXT;
    i                       record;
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_dependents_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_dependents_table (
    schema_name     varchar(255),
    table_oid       oid,
    table_name      varchar(255),
    level           smallint    
);

INSERT INTO tmp_dependents_table
SELECT DISTINCT
    ot.schema_name
    ,ot.table_oid
    ,ot.table_name
    ,ot.level
FROM related_tables_recursive(current_schema()) AS ot
INNER JOIN pg_attribute AS pga
ON pga.attrelid = ot.table_oid
WHERE   pga.attname = 'col_id'
    AND ot.level > 1
ORDER BY ot.level DESC NULLS LAST;

FOR i IN 
    SELECT * FROM tmp_dependents_table
LOOP
            
    v_query_delete := '';
    
    v_query_delete := 'DELETE FROM ' || i.schema_name || '.' || i.table_name
        || ' WHERE col_id = ' || p_id::TEXT || ';';
    
    RAISE NOTICE 'EXECUTING --> %', v_query_delete;
    EXECUTE v_query_delete;
    RAISE NOTICE 'EXECUTED DELETE.';
    
END LOOP;
    
END;
$function$
;
```

If I execute the `SELECT` statement alone that feeds the temp. table, I do get the relevant data, which is all the tables with a column called `col_id`

The logs (`RAISE NOTICE`) show the function is going through all the tables and performing the deletes fast, no problem, but the loop takes forever to exit.

The last logged `EXECUTED DELETE` is the last record in tmp_dependents_table.

I've looked for triggers, and indeed one of these tables (which holds 22k records when running the function on the test data I have) had one defined on DELETE. I've deleted that trigger.

I've looked for rules. The only ones I found for my schema are rules on SELECTs.

Is there anything else that could be triggered automatically making my code take much more time than needed to complete?

Comment: So, the COMMIT presumably is taking all the time. If you don't see any triggers, check what the system as a whole is doing - you might be saturating I/O.

Comment: @RichardHuxton there's isn't any way to see which statement(s) that are being commited are causing the slowdown ? The server is an AWS instance, so my troubleshooting tools are limited.

Comment: Does all the work need to be done in a single transaction?

Comment: @BrettDonald Not really, actually I would like to COMMIT every single DELETE's seperately so I can see which ones are slow. Don't know if I can commit explicitly from within a BEGIN block though

Comment: You should be able to use BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT inside your loop.

Comment: Any `FOREGN KEY` constraints pointing *towards* one of the processed tables? (Then it must be verified that no dependent rows exist.)

Comment: I turned my function into a procedure and COMMITed every delete on it's own. I think I found the culprit query: some FK violation. Why wouldn't the error come up when running the code as a function ?

Comment: It certainly **should** come up. Are you sure the function call actually succeeded? It must have been cancelled by the exception. (And the ensuing rollback can take some time,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some FK violations seem to have caused the problem. One possible solution: Define your FK constraints with [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-REFERENCES) - **if**  you want dependent rows to be deleted also.
See:

- [Delete rows with foreign key in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182079/delete-rows-with-foreign-key-in-postgresql/14182346#14182346)

While being at it, you can largely simplify your function, and make it cheaper and safer:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.delete_dependents(p_id smallint)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
   _tbl regclass;
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl IN 
      SELECT ot.table_oid  -- schema_name & table_name are redundant noise
      FROM   related_tables_recursive(current_schema()) ot  -- function can probably simplified, too
      WHERE  ot.level > 1  -- excludes null
      AND    EXISTS (
         SELECT FROM pg_attribute pga
         WHERE  pga.attrelid = ot.table_oid
         AND    pga.attname = 'col_id'
         AND    NOT pga.attisdropped  -- must be ruled out
         )
      GROUP BY ot.table_oid  -- why would you expect duplicates?
      ORDER BY max(ot.level) DESC, ot.table_oid
      -- nulls have been excluded, so no point in "NULLS LAST"
      -- make sort order unambiguous to avoid deadlocks with concurrent transactions
   LOOP
       -- _sql := '';  -- noise
       _sql := format('DELETE FROM %s WHERE col_id = $1', _tbl);

       RAISE NOTICE 'EXECUTING --> %', _sql;
       EXECUTE _sql USING p_id;  -- pass value as value
       RAISE NOTICE 'EXECUTED DELETE.';
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

You don't need a temporary table for this.

Your original is vulnerable to **SQL injection**. Identifiers have to be treated as possibly unsafe user input and must be double-quoted where necessary to be sure. About that, and the role of `regclass`:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)