# SQLAlchemy delete doesn't cascade

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

My `User` model has a relationship to the `Address` model. I've specified that the relationship should cascade the delete operation. However, when I query and delete a user, I get an error that the address row is still referenced. How do I delete the user and the addresses?

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', cascade='all,delete', backref='user')

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
```

```
db.session.query(User).filter(User.my_id==1).delete()
```

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) update or delete on table "user" violates foreign key constraint "addresses_user_id_fkey" on table "address"
DETAIL:  Key (my_id)=(1) is still referenced from table "address".
 'DELETE FROM "user" WHERE "user".id = %(id_1)s' {'id_1': 1}
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You have the following...

```
db.session.query(User).filter(User.my_id==1).delete()
```

Note that after "filter", you are still returned a Query object. Therefore, when you call `delete()`, you are calling `delete()` on the Query object (not the User object). This means you are doing a bulk delete (albeit probably with just a single row being deleted)

The [documentation for the `Query.delete()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy) method that you are using says...

> The method does not offer in-Python cascading of relationships - it is
>   assumed that ON DELETE CASCADE/SET NULL/etc. is configured for any
>   foreign key references which require it, otherwise the database may
>   emit an integrity violation if foreign key references are being
>   enforced.

As it says, running delete in this manner will ignore the Python cascade rules that you've set up. You probably wanted to do something like..

```
user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.my_id==1).first()
db.session.delete(user)
```

Otherwise, you may wish to look at [setting up the cascade for your database as well](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#on-update-and-on-delete).

Comment: Thank you so mcuh mark. For the first method to work, what changes would i have to make ?

Comment: @BadLuckBrian: This depends on the database you are using. Read the documentation I linked to at the end of my question for more info. Also, read the documentation for your database.

Comment: I am using posgress on Heroku. I added the cascade option to the Foregien Key column in the Addresses tables. Maybe Flask-Migrate may not have noticed this constraint had been added ? Could that of been possible ?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356484/how-to-add-on-delete-cascade-constraints). Not familiar with Postgres, but might be that you can't alter the schema to add the cascade after the foreign key constraint was already created.