# Is there a simple command to pack all database ids to have no gaps

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have my Postgres database which I used hibernate sequence to generate ids. But the sequence was common for all tables. But now my plan is to have a separate sequence for each table. Bow the what I would like to use a command to pack the ids continuous for a table, but without breaking any of the references.

Comment: Why would you need to "pack" id fields of the tables?

Comment: the old database contains ids generated with skips. Which i dont want to happen any more. And since the new ids pack them selfs nicely i would like to change old ids as well.

Comment: If you are using standard sequences to generate ids you will still have gaps in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make sure that all of your `FOREIGN KEY` references have `ON UPDATE CASCADE` (to add it: [How to add "on delete cascade" constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356484/how-to-add-on-delete-cascade-constraints) ), then you can use:

```
UPDATE mytable AS m
SET id = n.rank
FROM (SELECT id, rank() OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM mytable) AS n
WHERE m.id = n.id
```

Which will give you sequential IDs with the same order as the original ids:

```
> SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id;
id | name
1  | Alex
5  | David
10 | Jane
> UPDATE …;
…
> SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id;
id | name
1  | Alex
2  | David
3  | Jane
```

Comment: There might be some tables, that are referencing other `id` fields without a proper `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: There's no general solution to that, unfortunately — the only thing that can be done there is considering each column that contains an ad-hoc reference to another column and decide how to fix each one up on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: You may need to update your sequences after doing a mass update on your keys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/13308052