# Fastest way to delete rows from parent table PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that is being references by more than 1800 tables and these references are likely to increase with time. The table has around 180,000 records at the moment and a delete operation takes 12 secs on 13 rows. Similarly it takes around 12 minutes to delete 700 rows.

Database Design:

We have a data logging application that can have any number of forms thorough which operators can enter data for thousands of parameters. *The database design is inherited from an existing visualization application. It was a design requirement in visualization application to store each parameter's data in a separate table.* The data is collected against events that are created on a defined frequency which can be hourly, daily and monthly and so on. So, now we have a table for each parameter which has a foreign key column for event as well as the user.

In future I can see this problem happening on user deletion as well.

I have tried indexing all the foreign key references and there is no improvement in performance as suggested in [postgresql-and-primary-key-foreign-key-indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347370/postgresql-and-primary-key-foreign-key-indexing)

I have posted other details regarding my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59928694/delete-query-in-postgresql-taking-too-long?noredirect=1#comment105980792_59928694)

Please suggest a solution to optimize performance of delete, should I drop all the constraints?

edit:
Explain analyze query returns something like this:

```
"Delete on tbl_schedule  (cost=0.42..41.85 rows=13 width=6) (actual time=4.017..4.017 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using unique_key on tbl_schedule  (cost=0.42..41.85 rows=13 width=6) (actual time=0.025..0.047 rows=13 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (event_id_fk = 259)"
"Planning Time: 2.022 ms"
"Trigger for constraint tbl_103_186_fkey2: time=0.580 calls=13"
"Trigger for constraint tbl_103_187_fkey2: time=0.388 calls=13"
....
..
..
..
up to n(1800) tables.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see a potentially bigger problem here, namely that there are 1800 other tables which might have some connection to the table in question.  Optimizations aside, if this table has massive use, then _any_ operation may not perform well.  Maybe you can edit your question and tell us how you ended up with this design.

Comment: Can you provide execution plan? explain analyze would be nice. But BE CAREFUL! analyze runs query so be sure you are in transaction, BEGIN; explain analyze ...; ROLLBACK;

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Only deletes and (horribile dictu) key updates would be affected.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have posted some details regarding design at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59928694/delete-query-in-postgresql-taking-too-long?noredirect=1#comment105980792_59928694

if you need some more info let me know.

Comment: I agree with Tim, a single table referenced by that many tables might indicate a design that could be improved.@EhsanWaris: your link doesn't explain why `schedule` needs to be _referenced_ by so many other tables.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/

Comment: lets assume the design decision is not in my control at the moment. can we do anything to solve this problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated some details of design, hope it helps.