# In PostgreSQL does a foreign key constraint only require REFERENCES?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was reading the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html) on PostgreSQL constraints because I wanted to see how to define foreign keys. In their examples

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    product_no integer REFERENCES products (product_no),
    quantity integer
);
```

I don't see `FOREIGN KEY` anywhere; however, in several other stack overflow questions ([How to add "on delete cascade" constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356484/how-to-add-on-delete-cascade-constraints) for example) I have seen the `FOREIGN KEY` written. Is it necessary to write `FOREIGN KEY` or is it only necessary to use `REFERENCES`?

Comment: `references` works for a single column and it works in most databases.

Comment: So when would you use `foreign key`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good question.

You will notice `FOREIGN KEY` constraint in examples in [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html) related to DDL-constraints. I prefer to use `FOREIGN KEY` constraint as noted in Example 3 below.

You could do foreign key/references in different manners:

**Parent table**

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    price numeric
);
```

**Child table - Ex1**

Inline foreign key constraint without mentioning `FOREIGN KEY`

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    product_no integer REFERENCES products (product_no),
    quantity integer
);
```

OR

**Child table - Ex2**

Notice that parent and child table should have the same column name to use this concise notation.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    product_no integer REFERENCES products,
    quantity integer
);
```

OR

**Child table - Ex3**

Notice that we are explicitly using `FOREIGN KEY` keyword here.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    product_no integer,
    quantity integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_no) REFERENCES products (product_no),
);
```

In case when more than one fields need to be constrainted, `FOREIGN KEY` constraint can be written like this also:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  a integer PRIMARY KEY,
  b integer,
  c integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (b, c) REFERENCES other_table (c1, c2)
);
```

These examples are taken from the docs.

SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dd2d6

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You use `foreign key` primarily in three circumstances:

- You have a multi-key reference to another table.
- You want to name the foreign key reference.
- You want to add additional features, such as cascading deletes.

A fourth reason is also plausible:  because local coding standards require the use of an explicit constraint.

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept when I can. I would ask you to elaborate, but I don't think I'm at a level yet where the information would be useful.

Comment: @Bohemian . . . Do you know which databases do not? I'm pretty sure Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, and MySQL support inline references.

Comment: @Gordon I had a quick rummage around google and all the databases I've ever used (a fair few) support inline, so I've deleted my comment. I think it's pretty safe to say "all" databases support the inline *references* clause on a column def. Still, it felt good finding that out. And have a +1 for your troubles :)

Comment: @Bohemian: MySQL does not support "inline" foreign keys. They are parsed but (silently!) ignored

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name didn't know that :) Oddly, I had a suspicion that they didn't work with mysql, but I just skimmed the doc and got a hit. They are just like `check` constraints then. Is there anything it *doesn't* ignore? :(