# Add :on_delete to already existing foreign_key in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, foreign-keys, migration

I have already existing foreign key in database created this way:

```
class CreateUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table do ... end
    add_foreign_key :users, :admins, column: :admin_id
  end
end
```

but forgot to add `on_delete: :nullify`. Migration is already pushed & used on production. I want to add new migration which will add cascale deleting for this PK constraint. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can remove and add foreign key in next migration:

```
class ChangeForgeinKeyOnUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :users, column: :admin_id
    add_foreign_key :users, :admins, column: :admin_id, on_delete: :nullify
  end
end
```

Comment: also: if column is already populated with data don't forget to migrate data as well (i.e. select all and then insert all)

Comment: @RicardoGreen what I would do: 1. rename column (admin_id -> admin_id_copy); 2. add new column with name "admin_id", this time with constraint. 3. Copy data from admin_id_copy to admin_id column (you can just iterate in migration through collection :) but remember it will take a while for big DB). 4. drop admin_id_copy table

Comment: Is migrating the data really necessary? I think this drops just the contraint, not the whole column (data).
An alternative approach I used is to do everything directly in SQL (Postgres specific): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356484/how-to-add-on-delete-cascade-constraints

Comment: On PostgreSQL You do not need to "migrate" the column data. This just removes the foreign key from the table definition and re-adds it with a constraint. Column data isn't touched... however, that might be different for other databases.